# Given Fourier coefficients of a function , find the function

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

Given these Fourier coefficients:

$$
X[k]=\begin{cases}
1 & \text{, k even}\\
2 & \text{, k odd}\\
\end{cases}
$$
I want to find the analytical expression for the function.
What i tried was using the complex Fourier Series expression :
$$
 x(t)=\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} X[k]e^{jkw_0t}
$$
where $X[k]$ are the Fourier coefficients, j is the imaginary unit , $w_0=\frac {2\pi}T$ and T is the period , in this case $T=4$.  Now i'm kind of stuck in this series because i can't find out how to evaluated this sum , what i have so far is ( separated the even and odd terms  of the sum and i also assumed $a_o=0$):
$$
x(t)=\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} e^{j(2k)kw_0t} + \sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty 2e^{j(2k+1)kw_0t}
$$
What should i try next to calculate this sum?

Comment: Are you sure those are even the Fourier coefficients of anything? The sums don't converge for any $t$ (since the absolute value of each term is at least $1$ no matter what you do).

Comment: The Riemann-Lebesuge lemma assures us that these cannot be the Fourier coefficients of any function.

Comment: These are not the Fourier coefficients of a function, they're the Fourier coefficients of the distribution $$\pi(3\delta_0 - \delta_{\pi}).$$

Comment: @DanielFischer how did you reach that conclusion?And what exactly are the fourier coefficients of a distribution?

Comment: Working backwards from knowing roughly what the result would be, one can find the exact result by trial and error (by the way, I had originally forgotten the normalising factor, and I took $T = 2\pi$). If $F$ is a distribution on the unit circle, its Fourier coefficients are $\hat{F}(k) := \frac{1}{2\pi}F[e^{-ikt}]$, generalising the case when the distribution is given by an integrable function.